# Error installing gem capybara-webkit getting the following error: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-2.2

When installing the gemlock file I got the error of:
I'm in experienced with Ruby, but what I'm attempting to do is simply run the application from github. It's a quite old program written in 2015 (https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter)

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.15.1
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20201025-18652-1a6uktj.rb
extconf.rb
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-gl-dir
        --without-gl-dir
        --with-gl-include
        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
        --with-gl-lib
        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' failed

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.15.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/capybara-webkit-1.15.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.15.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.15.1'` succeeds before
bundling.

In Gemfile:
  capybara-webkit
```

The goal of this project is to download and run the ruby on rails application from git hub. It's an older app from 2015 which is why I've been running into so many dependency issues. Below is my gem file for further reference.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem 'timeout'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'activerecord-reset-pk-sequence'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'react-rails'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.5.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.13.7'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :test, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'selenium'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'byebug'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

``
```

Comment: Run just `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.15.1'` to see what errors you get. Sometimes you can get single gems to install. Most likely you are missing header files like the error says.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to know which OS are you using. As I can see its Windows?

On Mac you may have to install `qtwebkit`
On Ubuntu `Xvfb` can help.
But IDK how to handle this on windows